# Node, Lambda - building on windows deploying on Linux

Tags: aws-lambda

I want to deploy a lambda function written on a windows machine - to my AWS lambda. Using Upload as Zip - it takes all the node_modules and package file.

But I get an error

`errorMessage": "/var/task/node_modules/ibm_db/build/Release/odbc_bindings.node: invalid ELF header",`

How can I install a linux appropriate package from the DB2 driver?

Comment: Try with WSL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Answer (score 1):

You can use docker to run a Linux container with a shared volume between host and the container and build on the container.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Docker in windows can be painful at times, I had the same situation. 
Install Ubuntu (or any other distro ) in  [Windows](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-ubuntu-on-windows#2)
 from the Windows app store and then have all the dependencies installed and then use AWS CLI to zip the all the modules and upload in Lambda

A sample script can be like this

```
# Remove zip file if already exit
rm index.zip
# Creating zip file
zip -r index.zip *
# Update lambda function, the present directory name should be same as the lambda function name present in AWS
lambdaName=${PWD##*/}
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $lambdaName --zip-file fileb://index.zip
# Publish version
aws lambda publish-version --function-name $lambdaName
# Get latest version
version=$(aws lambda publish-version --function-name $lambdaName --description "updated via cli" --query Version | bc)
# Map alias to latest version
aws lambda update-alias --function-name $lambdaName \--function-version $version --name SANDBOX
# Create new alias
# aws lambda create-alias --function-name loyalty-gift-card-link-sl \ --function-version 2 --name SANDBOX2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, so I launched a t2.micro AWS linux instance, and installed docker, and created the Lambda package.

Here are the steps, if it helps you.

Launch new ec2 of amazonlinux from amzn-ami-hvm-2018.03.0.20181129-x86_64-gp2 (ami-01e24be29428c15b2)

install docker

```
sudo su
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
log out and log in to pickup the added group

cd /home/ec2-user/
mkdir <LambdaProject>
```

checkout code from repo

```
git clone <repo>
```

build docker, and install Node.js 6.10 along with dependencies

```
cd /home/ec2-user/
docker build --tag amazonlinux:nodejs .
```

Install the sharp and querystring module dependencies (OR What you need), and compile the ‘Origin-Response’ function

```
docker run --rm --volume ${PWD}/lambda/origin-response-function:/build amazonlinux:nodejs /bin/bash -c "source ~/.bashrc; npm init -f -y; npm install sharp --save; npm install querystring --save; npm install url --save; npm install path --save; npm install --only=prod"

mkdir -p dist && cd lambda/origin-response-function && zip -FS -q -r ../../dist/origin-response-function.zip * && cd ../..
```

Package the ‘Origin-Response’ function.

```
mkdir -p dist && cd lambda/origin-response-function && zip -FS -q -r ../../dist/origin-response-function.zip * && cd ../..
```

Note: package is created as dist/origin-response-function.zip

create S3 bucket in us-east-1 region to hold the deployment files and upload the zip files created in above steps. NOTE: You can add triggers only for functions in the US East (N. Virginia) Region.
Bucket:

copy lambda package to s3 bucket

```
aws s3 cp dist/origin-response-function.zip s3://<bucket_name>/
```